# file reader not working in fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

I have a page use fileReader to preview the upload image.

I have test in my local machine, it works fine, but when I test in JS fiddle, it is not working. anyone know where is the problem?

```
if(window.FileReader){  
    function preview(input){
        if(input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            reader.onload = function(e){$('#previewImage').attr('src', e.target.result);}            
        }
    }
}else{alert("file reader not support");}
```

here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s39P3/93/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the console open you will see the error is that the 'preview' function isn't found, because it isn't part of the scope.  I added it to the window scope so `window.preview = function()` and now it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/s39P3/93/

Comment: how about jcrop, it works fine in my local machine too, but only 1st time, if it wont work if i try to switch another image